# Make R REPL use the full Shell

Tags: r, shell

I am using the R repl quite extensively to learn R.

The only problem is that if I type more than 80 characters, the R REPL beings to hide previously typed characters (in other words it will not show more than 80 characters... so always shows the last 80 characters)

it beings to show a "$" sign to indicate that it has gone past 80. see below

[image]

But I don't like this behavior and I want it to take the full length of the console whatever the windows/linux shell is set to.

can R shell behave like the normal shell where it rolls over to the new line if I type more than the configured width of the shell?

Comment: `options(width=...)`

Comment: does not work. I did `options(width=150)` but it still has exact the same behavior